# How to save data from form.ModelForm in database and also show new post in template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

> I render the template for creation new post but nothing show on browser
> I'm working on django framework

View.py

```
def create_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.date_posted = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'form': form})
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, fields

from .models import Post
    
    
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
           model = Post
           fields = ['title', 'description', 'date_posted', 'author']
```

urls.py

```
from django.http import request
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('create/', views.create_post, name='create-post'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

Comment: The logic seems to be good. Can you share your `urls.py` file. And if you have an specific error please add it to the answer. And detail what is wrong with your code.

Comment: urls.py:
from django.http import request
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('create/', views.create_post, name='create-post'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),

]

Nothing show in template

Comment: Please add that in your answer, edit your question to make it easy to understand to other who will checkout your question and try to help you.

Comment: And at this point add also what's wrong with you code.

Comment: sure bro, i'll change it.

Comment: Can you check if `form.is_valid()` returns true?